# Laravel validation required if field not equal to

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.7, laravel-validation

I have custom validation rule in my controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'currency' => [
        'required',
        'numeric',
        'min:0',
        'max:7'
    ],
    'price' => [
        'nullable',
        "required_if:currency, !=, 0",
        'numeric',
        'min:1',
        'max:1000000'
    ],
], $messages);
```

Why work in `required_if:currency, ==, 0` and not work in this `required_if:currency, !=, 0` case?

In my case `price` field required only when `currency` field value not equal to `0`

I tired also:

```
required_unless,currency,0
required_unless:currency,0
```

Comment: Why not try if currency greater than 0? i.e. `currency => gt:12`

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest you use

> `required_unless:currency,0`
>   according to   [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-unless

Answer (score 3):

`required_if:currency, ==, 0` works because the `currency` value must be equal to any of the values that follow the value name (in this case `currency`). In other words, `price` is required in this case if currency is either `==` or `0`.

So the `==` doesn't mean the usual "equals" in this case. It is just taken as a **string value**. That is also why `required_if:currency, !=, 0` does not work as you expected it to.

To make the `price` field required only when the `currency` field value is not equal to 0, you could use `required_unless:currency,0`.

In other words, `price` is always required, unless `currency` is equal to 0.

Comment: Not working in my case too, but everyone suggests this format like you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Rule::requiredIf($request->get('currency') != 0)
```

Comment: That's right! using Model "Illuminate\Validation\Rule".